# Standards for how developers work on their own workstations

Tags: development-process, coding-standards

We've just come across one of those situations which occasionally comes up when a developer goes off sick for a few days mid-project.

There were a few questions about whether he'd committed the latest version of his code or whether there was something more recent on his local machine we should be looking at, and we had a delivery to a customer pending so we couldn't wait for him to return.

One of the other developers logged on as him to see and found a mess of workspaces, many seemingly of the same projects, with timestamps that made it unclear which one was "current" (he was prototyping some bits on versions of the project other than his "core" one).

Obviously this is a pain in the neck, however the alternative (which would seem to be strict standards for how each developer works *on their own machine* to ensure that any other developer can pick things up with a minimum of effort) is likely to break many developers personal work flows and lead to inefficiency on an individual level.

I'm not talking about standards for checked-in code, or even general development standards, I'm talking about how a developer works locally, a domain generally considered (in my experience) to be almost entirely under the developers own control.

So how do you handle situations like this?  Are the one of those things that just happens and you have to deal with, the price you pay for developers being allowed to work in the way that best suits them?

Or do you ask developers to adhere to standards in this area - use of specific directories, naming standards, notes on a wiki or whatever?  And if so what do your standards cover, how strict are they, how do you police them and so on?

Or is there another solution I'm missing?

[Assume for the sake of argument that the developer can not be contacted to talk through what he was doing here - even if he could knowing and describing which workspace is which from memory isn't going to be simple and flawless and sometimes people genuinely can't be contacted and I'd like a solution which covers all eventualities.]

**Edit:** I get that going through someone's workstation is bad form (though it's an interesting - *and likely off-topic* - question as to precisely why that is) and I'm certainly not looking at unlimited access.  Think more along the lines of a standard where their code directories are set up with a read-only share - nothing can be changed, nothing else can be seen and so on.

Comment: -1 for going Gestapo on a programmer's command center.

Comment: Wait, how did the second developer know the first developer's password?

Comment: @TheLQ - The first developer told him then changed it when he got back.  We're a small company and there's a good level of trust that this sort of thing won't be abused.  This is incidentally something that the developers did / decided between themselves rather than something management forced on them.

Comment: Is this why daily builds are recommended? May give a reason to check in more often?

Comment: @Geoffrey - If that were true, the -1 *might* be fair (it actually wouldn't as the question is about how to *avoid* doing what you describe as "going Gestapo" therefore is surely a good question about how to avoid a bad situation).  As it was it was two developers working together to address a situation they had come across, coming up with an approach they were happy with no direction or other input from management as to go about it so, with all due respect, you're just demonstrating Godwin's law.

Comment: +1 for an excellent question. "Going gestapo" is not relevant in a corporate environment in my opinion since developers are working for the corporation and therefore relinquish access rights to their local machines. You want privacy, use your own hardware.

Comment: If the developer could be contacted for the password, why didn't you just ask him which version was the current one?

Comment: @Gary: what? no, that’s complete (and very dangerous) nonsense. It’s a looong shot (both logically and legally) from working for a company to giving up personal rights for privacy. I wouldn’t call Jon’s action “going Gestapo” (even before he explained it more) but companies *do* go Gestapo sometimes and this is something that needs to be prevented and fought on all levels. I can only speak for Germany but here you *do* have certain privacy rights even when working on company-owned hardware.

Comment: @Konrad I'm pretty sure that all corporate environments permit a root user (or domain admin) access to their networked machines. Bang goes your privacy in terms of secrecy and rifling through your stuff. Of course, how a company acts on that information is subject to privacy laws (they can't legally reveal your Facebook password for example). There is no real way to mitigate this since they can install any logging software they like as part of a corporate security policy. Again: you want privacy, use your own hardware. And don't store your private keys on their machines.

Comment: @Gary: well, for one thing, installing a logging software is usually illegal under German law.

Comment: @Ben - Because he was going from memory and there were 10 or 12 workspaces containing duplicates of a single project.  But the question asks that the assumption be made that he wouldn't be contactable in any case as that's more likely to be the case.

Comment: @Konrad - It's sort of an aside to the question but my view would be that going Gestapo *is* the right of the company but one it should invoke only as a last resource and should do so understanding that there are likely to be significant ramifications in doing so.  My understanding is that the legal position is usually (dependent on country), if it's their kit, they're allowed to do so, so long as it's for a genuine business reason and not just for snooping.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

"**If it's not in source control, it doesn't exist.**"

This is one of the few things in our profession that I'm borderline dogmatic about. For the following reasons:

1. Even though the workstation is company property, let's face it - there is a bit of an unwritten rule that a programmer's own workstation is his/her castle. I'm just uneasy with a workplace culture where anyone can routinely log onto it and go through it.
2. Everybody has their own flow (as you said as well). Trying to force all developers to organise their own local workspaces a certain way may go against their particular way of working, and break their flow and make them less efficient.
3. Stuff that isn't in source control is half-baked code. If it's fully baked code that's ready for release, it should be in source control. Which comes back again to the main point....
4. "If it's not in source control, it doesn't exist."

One possible way to mitigate the issue of wanting to look at code on people's workstations is to foster a culture of regular checkins. I worked at a company once where - even though there was no official mandate to do so - it was seen a sort of point of pride to always have everything checked in for the weekend. In maintenance and release candidate phases, CR items were deliberately very fine grained to allow for small, cleanly visible changes, and regular checkins to keep track of them.

Also, having everything checked in before you go on vacation was *mandatory*.

**TL;DR version**: Rifling through people's workstations is bad form. Rather than trying to foster a culture of making it easy to go through people's workstations to find what we want, it's better practice to foster a culture of sensible source control use and regular checkins. Possibly even hyper-regular checkins, and fine-grained tasks when in critical phases of projects.

Comment: +1: Someone's out sick, messing around on their workstation is probably going to be more cost than value.  One person's already gone.  Now another is wasting time trying to figure out what's going on.  Huge management nightmare for no value.  Until it's in source control, it never existed.

Comment: If he's off for the day? Yup, for the rest of the week? Maybe, for a month? No chance. This is one of those nasty "shades of grey" problems... we're back, again, to commit early, commit often - so the patterns don't necessarily need to be workstations but use of version control, but clearly its something worth thinking about.

Comment: When you say release, do you mean release for the build or release to users?

Comment: @Murph:  If the changes are committed somewhere every X days, the maximum amount of work that can be misplaced is X days' worth, and that's true no matter how long the developer is unavoidably out.  The proper thing to do is to have policies about checking in frequently enough so that the amount of lost work is within acceptable bounds.

Comment: @Guzica The mention of "If it's fully baked code that's ready for release, it should be in source control." While true it should also be in source control when a stopping point is reached. Taking the approach you mention is precisely why a developer hoards their code on a local machine until it is "fully baked".

Comment: @Guiza, I disagree with computers being personal castles.  It is the property of the company, not the programmer, and should be treated as such, similar to desks and chairs.  That is customarily is primarily used by a single person does not change this.  The exception is naturally classified material, but programmers rarely work with that.

Comment: @David my comment was a response to that of @S.Lott - in terms of the argument about "lost". Well sort of. I want commits to be atomic in the sense of a complete set of changes (I'm beginning to understand why rebase is so attractive a notion) - so I see "commit to save" as problematic (in the general instance and in the absence of a rebase equivalent). And in any case there should be daily automated workstation backups quite distinct from version control.

Comment: @Murph:  You seemed to be implying that it had something to do with how long the developer was out, and I didn't understand that.  How much work can be lost doesn't depend on that.  The work is more likely to be needed if the developer is out a long time, but if there isn't that much pending at any given time there's not that much lost anyway.

Comment: Legalities aside, it's quite disrespectful to open up a machine to rummage through code. Bad management (not requiring regular commits) does not ease the disrespect.  A partial solution is to store working copies on a network drive that can be accessed in emergencies.

Comment: @Jeff O: Release for the build.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Oh, of course it is. I'm talking more about the subtlety of that "primarily used by one developer". Basically, as I explained, I think something is broken if you have to constantly log onto developers' workstations and look at what's in the local workspaces. So if you treat that as an absolute emergency last resort, it helps good SC and build/release practices. I'm not implying any kind of real, actual right to "owning" the workstation as such though. Just an unwritten rule that it's bad form to go through it as a matter of routine.

Answer (score 21):

Rather than enforcing a standard for how your developers organize their workstations, **enforce a standard where all work is checked in at the end of each day**. The check-ins could be to branches if still incomplete.

This way no one should ever need to access another developer's workstation.

I would imagine that this policy would meet with some opposition, but nothing compared to what I would expect if you enforced rules about the organization of ones workstation.

Comment: How often would you merge the branch?  Every time you felt it was stable?

Comment: @Jon Hopkins: "Releasable" is easier to manage than "Stable".  Releasable includes stable as well as product owner is ready for it.  And you'll do a lot of branch-to-release processing.  Branch-to-stable has too much potential for subjectivity and "worked for me" discussion.

Comment: -1 I disagree with this without a huge amount of qualification, checkins should occur at a logical point - and not arbitrarily at the end of the day. (Yes, we should aim not to leave 'til we've got to a sensible breakpoint but life doesn't always cooperate.) Backups should be distinct. And we all need to be a bit less precious about access to our boxes (not *changes* to, *access* to)

Comment: -1 because this does not address scenarios like "I feel really sick, I'm going home right now. Hmm, better just do another 30mins of preparation so I don't break the build when I commit."

Comment: Most absences are known well in advance. Even if someone doesn't do the daily build that one time, doesn't mean it isn't a good idea the rest of the year.

Comment: @Jeff: "Most absences are known well in advance" - not if you've got kids or a local cafe with poor food hygiene standards.

Comment: @Murph Checkins into 'trunk' or mainline (whatever you want to call it) should only occur as you describe. However, there is nothing wrong with having developers 'save their work at the end of the day' by committing to a personal branch (although this is a lot easier with git or mercurial than with SVN). And compared to enforcing guidelines on how developers workstations are configured (which was our starting point) it is a downright sane solution.

Comment: @Gary Rowe How doesn't it? You check into a branch. Takes all of two seconds and no need to worry about breaking the build (which would not be based on a personal branch).

Comment: @Kris I agree wholeheartedly with the general principle of "If it's not in source control it don't exist", my problem comes with enforcing the mandatory check in before you leave under all possible circumstances. It seems too dogmatic. I'd rather take some small pain in the rare occasions that a check in is missed and causes problems to others than have a million unfinished dubiously named broken branches all over my version control. Also, not all version control systems offer easy branching (imagine this rule applied to VSS or StarTeam).

Comment: Daily "unstable" checkins and all kinds of branches and such, with associated history, may quickly make a mess of your SCM.  However, I am a fan of a feature of TFS called "Shelvesets" which is essentially the same thing - it holds file(s) in a named set (with an appropriate comment), which could be shared among team members.  You could conceivably put everything you are working on into a shelveset every day, without clogging up source control.

Comment: Any non-trivial piece of work does not necessarily end up in a commitatable state at the end of the day.

Comment: What are your qualifications for committable?  The end of the day seems perfect.  Commits are footnotes to explain changes.  Half made changes that I haven't seen in a while need the most explanation.

Comment: This could be solved with DVCS running a read-only server locally or having per-user repos on the shared code server. And you can layer DVCS:es on top of SVN if want,..

Answer (score 7):

A few months back I was working on a rather large project and had to leave work abruptly as I found out I was being admitted to the hospital.  I did not have time to check in my latest code for the project.

Luckily, it is convention here (though not "necessary") to store code in `/var/www/ourdomain.com` to mimic production. With such a logical, and easy to follow convention, it was easy for a co-worker to login to my machine and retrieve my latest changes.

I think some conventions are good. Though I agree with Bobby when he says

"If it's not in source control, it doesn't exist."

Also, a useful addition to any programmers workspace could be a front-bay hot-swap SATA drive on which to store all source and development projects. This way, if such a problem does arise, an employee can retrieve new source changes to the project easily without the need to login to the developers workstation.

Comment: "... it doesn't exist". To others, that is.

Answer (score 6):

I'll tell you the truth I feel uneasy about the very idea that somebody is going to log in on to my machine and browse through my stuff. Granted, it's the company equipment and property, but it is simply a bad thing to do.

Last time I left for a weekend the guys reconfigured the servers with the database and source control and for some reason felt it necessary to log in on to my machine and reconfigure the system for the new setting.

Too bad they had no idea what they were doing and they erased a prototype I had been working on for the last two months.

It wouldn't have happened if the proper communication was in place. That's what you need as well. Get to that developer and find out the state of the things. Even better, ask people for a report before they go on leave so that you take an informed decision whether you need anything of them or not.

But don't mess with people's workstations.

P.S. We do have a convention for a directory structure but it's main existence reason is a mix of history/configuration - put it anywhere else and it won't compile.

Comment: That's a poor answer (not quite enough to downvote) - I'm entirely sympathetic but there's a significant difference between logging on to find something and logging on to change things without consultation. Further the question quite specifically stated that the developer had gone "off sick" - so the problem is dealing with unforseen circumstances and hence the need for a system.

Comment: @Murph: Going "off sick" accompanied by an urgent need to get something from his system is a really rare situation. May not be worth any standardization efforts.

Comment: Besides if the guy hasn't checked it in, then it is not ready. Why risk with the code in an unknown state? What if there is something tiny he was meant to get to the next day, you don't notice it, believe you've completed it, put it in production and then boom!

Comment: @Developer Art - the theory was that a developer could potentially polish up what he had faster than start it from scratch, even if it wasn't ready.

Comment: I can understand why someone should read your mail and shouldn't change anything on your machine but how about if it was standard to share (read-only) your code directories?  That would get round most of what I perceive as your objections but still allow people the possibility of getting to your work in an emergency.

Comment: In terms of the communications - as I say, this was sickness, not leave.  He obviously didn't know he was going to be sick (he has a good sick record) and couldn't be contacted.  I do take the point that we may be dealing in edge cases so specific as to not be worth addressing.

Comment: @Developer Art = in much the same way as internet failure co-inciding with a key delivery date. Except that it somehow manages too. Besides I would have other concerns about the described working patterns (from painful experience). System may be too strong a word - but "pattern" for dev boxes might be appropriate.

Comment: No backup on that prototype?

Comment: @Jeff O: No, no backup. Wasn't that important. Anyway was sort of stupid to lose it by the hands of one of our own.

Comment: @Developer art, why did you not work in a branch of the versioning system?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: Because we're not using that option sadly. Not my decision. Actually *were* not using it since I no longer work there.

Comment: @DeveoperArt, what do you mean "not using that option"?  You mean there was no way for you to just create a branch on your own?  Did they somehow disable branching?  I've never heard of that possibility.  Even so, you could have created your own "git" (or even "svn") repository on your own local machine (perhaps backed up to Dropbox or a network drive) without involving anyone else.  I just can't relate personally to working on something for 2 months (or even 2 *hours*, really) whether "important" or not, and having only 1 copy of it.

Comment: @SpashHit: Basically I was told not to introduce branching because "we won't be doing things that way". As to having backed up it to a network drive, here you are correct, I could have done but sadly didn't. Nobody ever did anything on their own accord on my machine and suddenly after two years the admin (I suppose) let himself on my machine and just erased the local copy of the project (because it was no longer in sync with the new directory structure I think). I didn't account for something like that.

Comment: @Developer Art, not to rub salt in your wound, but there are other scenarios that you may have anticipated, such as a hardware failure, or your own fat fingers, which would have indicated backing up your work in some way

Answer (score 4):

The first part of your question identify communication problems within your team clearly. Have you tried [daily standups](http://martinfowler.com/articles/itsNotJustStandingUp.html)?

I agree with you when you say that standards will probably lead to inefficiency if they are too strict. Standards must be defined by the **team**, involving everybody.

In your case, I would wait few days after the concerned developer return at work. Then organize a meeting to talk about those standards.

In order to avoid any psychological blocks and resistance, don't name persons or specific things you saw. Keep it general, the goal here is to get input from everybody, including the developer you think should improve his way of working. The guy may consider your organization as a mess too.

During the meeting present the problem and ask clearly how the **team** could improve the situation.

> The (whole) **team** decide what to do.

Answer (score 3):

That user was probably suffering from a lack of proper tools. In particular, the use of a distributed version control system would have eliminated for him the need to have different directories of code in different states. He could have kept that all in branches and been much happier.

To the main point, though, no I don't want standards enforced on me on how I organize my own workstation. I'm currently pushing back about my department standardizing on an IDE (my boss REALLY wants us all in Eclipse because it's what he uses and knows well, even though IMO it's not the best tool for *my* job).

Let developers do whatever makes them comfortable. A comfortable developer is more productive than an uncomfortable one. And if somebody's NOT productive, and you suspect they're fumbling around locally with the tools, it's an opportunity for training, not a Good Time to Make New Rules.

Comment: How would that help?  The question would still exist, we'd just be talking about which branch within his local DVCS repository rather than which workspace.

Comment: Don't assume its the tools - its also appreciation of how best to make use of the tools that can be lacking. What's obvious to some needs to be shown to others. The anti-pattern of lots copies of the source tree is one I've seen a few times. Yes, DVCS can help - but in this context we'd still have an issue with identifying the right branch and - if we want to go further - with making those Work In Progress branches available. @Jon the local DVCS should automagically push to that user's "backup" of their repository. At the very least if moves the problem off their box.

Comment: @Jon -- I guess the point is, his diverse branches would be in something that would have merging functionality built into it, rather than just scattered directories of diverging files. Plus, getting him up and going on the DVCS would have been a training opportunity.

Comment: @Dan - But some of those branches are dead ends - proofs of concept, things with assorted debug code in that you don't want merged in, older versions.  The fact you have merge functionality doesn't help when you don't know what you should be merging.

Comment: @Jon - I guess that's true. Maybe there's just no recovering from somebody really committed to making a mess.

Comment: @Jon - The other thing is (and this isn't obviously a cure-all) but you could at least use gitx or whatever to at least get a quick view of what's IN the changes between the branches. Much easier than trying to manually diff multiple working directories.

Comment: @Dan Ray:  One person's organized workspace is another person's mess.  The developer might have no problems with managing the multiple copies; perhaps they're named something he can remember.  Different people work in different ways, and forcing everybody to work the same risks lower morale and productivity in general to make it somewhat easier to cope with a rare contingency.

Answer (score 3):

At my old place of work, we had a system whereby each task in our bugtracking had it's own branch in source control. It was understood that most of the time, one bug/task is squashed by one developer so broken code was allowed to be checked into source control.

Once the code was in a state that it was stable on the development branch, a rebase was done dragging code in from the branch you were going to integrate with. Once you'd tested that merge, it would simply be a case of committing the code to the integration branch - it would require no merging as you'd already done the merge on your branch.

This way, you save the problem of developers worrying about committing code that's broken - and you can begin to apply social policy of making it super acceptable to check code in before you leave the office at night - nice and safe.

Answer (score 2):

In *this* particular situation call the person at home, make it very clear that you are not doubting that he is ill but you need to have somebody else continue his work, and ask where the latest stuff is and in what state.

Then you need to consider what to do from here.  If the problem is that people check in too seldom, consider using a distributed source control system that allows people to work in branches without disturbing one another.

If the problem is that you don't like developers having multiple workspaces on their machine, then get over it.  Working style is individual and you should basically stay away from their systems as long as they work fine with the rules for the source repository.  Personally I check out a new copy very frequently for different projects and only clean up once in a while.

If the problem is that you don't know what your developer is doing, the problem is political not technical, and you need to change your style of management.  Please remember that developers are highly skilled personel who rarely like micromanagement and you *have to* delegate.  Otherwise you will push the most skilled individuals away.

So, I would recommend encouraging a better way to work with the common source repository - say it is fine for people to work in branches, and let them commit frequently as long as they synchronize up their local copy to the master repository daily (as they will always do development work in a branch this will not influence others).

Comment: I did specifically say in the question to assume that the person can't be contacted.

Comment: @Jon, in that case consider his unfinished work lost, assign it to another programmer, and then start pondering on why this happened in the first place.

Comment: There's a logical inconsistency in there - "you don't know what your developer is doing" vs "you have to delegate" which means you know *what* he's doing but possibly not *how* - which in turn is why you need to get at the code... (yes, communication may help to sort this out but if you trust your devs to solve a problem and its a smallish problem - for a given dev - then "go fix this, bye!" may be as much management as is needed).

Comment: @Murph, then enforce a rule of "commit often - in a branch" and push to central at least daily.

Answer (score 2):

> So how do you handle situations like
>   this?

You can solve this problem with a source control system that supports personal unstable branches and by maintaining frequent commits.  A commit does not have to come when an entire problem is solved.  It should come whenever you benefit from source control.  The end of the day is one of many points when a commit should happen so that you can see where your changes were made, back them up, and explain them to your future self or others.

> Or do you ask developers to adhere to standards in this area - use of
>   specific directories, naming
>   standards, notes on a wiki or
>   whatever?

We have an immense environment configuration document that denotes conventions, but not a standard.  Standards are for production code and environments.  However many of our development tools are setup to support the conventions and most developers don't expend effort bucking the trend.